# How can I combine two arrays for a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I'm stuck on this for a while now: I'm trying to combine two arrays, one is every image in a folder, and the other one is the description of the picture from the SQL Database. In the database I've added the filename and the apartment name. To make my query work I need it to be in a loop, but to show the results of my query, it needs to become a loop, so I would think it must be possible to combine it right? But I can't seem to figure out how to combine these two arrays in a loop. I've tried with two loops and this is what I've got:

```
<?php

$directory = "images/photos/";
$images = glob('images/photos/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $sqlaa = "SELECT * FROM `afbeelding` WHERE filename = ' . $image . '";
    $titles = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaa);

    while ($row = $titles->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<form action="" method="post"><li>
              <a href="' . $image . '" title="' . $row['apartment'] . '" >
                  <img style="width:150px;height:150px;" src="' . $image . '" />
              </a>
              </li>';
    }
}
?>
```

If anyone knew, that'd be great!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have one row in `afbeelding` table per image?

Comment: You may be able to remove your loop over $images.  Instead of `WHERE filename = $value` you could do `WHERE filename IN ($listOfValues)`.  In general, I find that having to do a loop involving a repeated query means I have either designed my database poorly or I can revise my query to get all the data at once.

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu Ofcourse, filename and apartment, so every file can be linked at an apartment

Comment: @SurrealDreams When I delete my $image loop, my images won't show anymore. Its a loop for echoing every image in a folder. Would be pointless without it

Comment: How is it pointless? you have your `$directory` and you have a `filename` field from database, `$directory . $row['filename']` should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, true, I wasn't paying attention to the rest of the loop.  At any rate, I was suggesting something like @Igor's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about... going about it differently.

You already have the filenames in database.
So just poll your database with your available data, and then just echo it.
I'm assuiming it's stored as `images/photos/filename.jpg` in your database.
But without a data sample as is in your database I can't speculate more.

```
$directory = "images/photos/";

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $sqlaa = "SELECT * FROM `afbeelding` WHERE filename like '%images/photos/%'";
    $titles = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaa);

    while ($row = $titles->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<form action="" method="post"><li>
              <a href="' . $image . '" title="' . $row['apartment'] . '" >
                  <img style="width:150px;height:150px;" src="' . $row['filename'] . '" />
              </a>
              </li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, @VitaliiStrimbanu thank you too, you were right. I was thinking too difficult

Answer (score 2):

You can try making the loop over the data and then check the image in the loop, this could be faster and avoids using a query inside a loop.

```
<?php

$directory = "images/photos/";
//$images = glob('images/photos/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$sqlaa = "SELECT filename,apartment FROM `afbeelding`";
$titles = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaa);
while($row = $titles->fetch_array())
{
   $image=$row["filename"];
   if (file_exists($directory.$image)){
     echo '<form action="" method="post"><li>
      <a href="'.$image.'" title="' . $row['apartment'] . '" >
      <img style="width:150px;height:150px;" src="'.$image.'" />
      </a>
      </li>';
  }
}
?>
```

I don't know if the image is stored using the full relative path "images/photos/img.png" or the base filename only "img.png".

If the data in `afbeelding` is huge, you can improve the sql query using an IN filter

```
function imageNames($item){
    return "'$item'";
}

$images = glob('images/photos/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$names=array_map("imageNames",$images);
$filter_names=implode(",",$names);

$sqlaa = "SELECT filename,apartment FROM `afbeelding` WHERE filename IN ($filter_names)";
```

And then proceed with the loop, without checking files.

Answer (score 0):

first: loops on db-calls are not really best practice..

A possible result to your question:

```
<?php

$directory = "images/photos/";
$images = glob('images/photos/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$images = array_flip($images);

// get data first
foreach($images as $image => $v) {
    $sqlaa = "SELECT * FROM `afbeelding` WHERE filename = ' . $image . '";
    $titles = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaa);

    if ($title->num_rows == 1) {
        $row = $titles->fetch_array();
        $images[$image] = $row['apartment'];
    } else {
        $images[$image] = '';
    }
}

// render data
foreach ($images as $filename => $description) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post"><li>
        <a href="'.$filename.'" title="' . $description . '" >
            <img style="width:150px;height:150px;" src="'.$filename.'" />
        </a>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

Not really nice, but plain simple..